# Import CV Page Not Found

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I get a page not found when trying to import my Careers profile.
I was half way through writing my new story when I realised I could import.

Any ideas?

Comment: Oops, this was not supposed to be a link. On it.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to trying this out

Comment: I assume you're middle-clicking it? Should work just fine as is with a simple click. We're still changing it, but I guess you could try it out, in case you don't want to wait :)

Comment: It's a regular single click. I'm on latest OSX and Latest Firefox. Pretty sure it's a normal click because I don't know how to do middle click on the trackpad :(

Comment: Hah! Worry not, fix incoming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your report. This has now (hopefully) been fixed. I replaced the link with a proper submit button. Since it's a POST-only route, a link didn't make much sense anyways.

<3